# How many raw data records are read during each iteration of the data step in the following program?

Tags: sas

The following is the program. Many thanks for your time and attention.

```
data WORK.INFO;
     infile 'DATAFILE.TXT';
     input @1 Company $20. @25 State $2. @;
     if State=' ' then input @30 Year;
     else input @30 City Year; 
     input NumEmployees;
  run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input data is formatted as expected then 2 raw data records would be read during each iteration of the data step.

Ordinarily when an `input` statement is executed, the next `input` statement would read the next raw data record. However your first `input` statement has what is known as a "trailing @", i.e. an `@` symbol followed by semicolon `;`, in this case the input pointer remains on the same raw data record ready for the next `input` statement, which in your case is executed as a result of the `if-then-else`.

The last `input` statement before the `run` reads 1 raw data record.

So:

```
input @1 Company $20. @25 State $2. @;
```

reads data from one record and:

```
if State=' ' then input @30 Year;
     else input @30 City Year;
```

finishes reading data from the ***same*** raw data record. Lastly:

```
input NumEmployees;
```

reads data from the next raw data record. The data step finishes that iteration and so has read from 2 raw data records.

A general discussion of the `input` statement syntax & usage would be quite wide so I've limited it to the example you have shown. This [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm) has a lot more explanation and the Example 3 given in the link shows usage of a "trailing @" like in your code.